# Selecting Captured values from a String

Tags: php, regex

I have the following String for a Schedule

```
Jun 4, 2018 => Jun 12, 20018
```

What I'm trying to do is to get each value of each Date like the following:

```
$schedule = explode('=>', 'Jun 4, 2018 => Jun 12, 20018');
foreach ($schedule as $date) {
    preg_match('/([a-z]{3})|(\b[0-9]{2}\b)|([0-9]{4})/i', $date, $values);
    $day = $values[1];
    $month = $values[0];
    $year = $values[2];
    echo $day.'-'.$month.'-'.$year;
}
```

What I expected is to get each Captured Group from the `preg_match()` in the `$values` by its order in the string, The final result I expect is

```
4-6-2018
12-6-2018
```

Same goes to Samples like

```
   Jan 2007 =expected-result> 0-6-2018
   12 2007 =expected-result> 12-0-2018
   2007 =expected-result> 0-0-2018
```

But I get an error instead

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: value -- at line 8
Jun-Jun-
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: value -- at line 8
Jun-Jun-
```

I don't know if that is possible using `DateTime` instead of `RegEx` Since the Date format isn't static and has 3 different formats.

Comment: Try [`preg_match('~([a-z]{3})\s*([0-9]{1,2}),\s*([0-9]{4})~i', $date, $values);`](https://regex101.com/r/P2C5gR/1). Note you have `20018`, but it must probably be `2018`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew gave me `Jun-Jun 4, 2018-4    [newline]            
Jun-Jun 12, 2001-12`

Comment: That is the problem with your code. Use the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using:

```
$year = $value[2];
```

But you are missing the 's' on the end of $value. Change it to:

```
$year = $values[2];
```

BTW, you may have an easier time using something like:

```
$schedule = explode('=>', 'Jun 4, 2018 => Jun 12, 2018');
$start = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($schedule[0])) ;
$end = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($schedule[1])) ;
```

Comment: It works ok with all the cases but `4 2018 - 12 2018` while giving current day or month of the other part doesn't exists

Comment: same with `2007 => 2007`

Comment: Do you have any control over the data/dates you are receiving? Maybe making sure your date have some sort of standard (or predictable) formatting would help.

Comment: Nope, Only the ability to select and change the values using php, not allowed to update nor insert.

Comment: @Toleo, the data has to be coming from somewhere. The less control you have over your input the more complicated your code will have to be to try to interpret and/or validate it.

Comment: I understand, You question solved a part if it anyway, If you can tell me if it is possible to change the default empty values to 0 instead of the current date, that would be complete

Comment: @Toleo, if you know you don't have a value then you could change the date format to use '0-m-Y', but that means you already know you don't have a value. I'm not sure why you would want a 0 in a date rather than a 1.

Comment: Table uses `Datetime` format which requires me not to use Day or Months because they're used later in the code.